# How to host Moqui on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, hosting, moqui

Is there a way to host Moqui on AWS? I was trying to host Moqui using a EC2 instance but couldn't figure out a way to connect them.

Answer (score 0):

The Run and Deploy document on moqui.org has a section for a simple recommended deployment using ElasticBeanstalk and RDS:

https://www.moqui.org/m/docs/framework/Run+and+Deploy#AWSElasticBeanstalkandRDS

With more details about how you want to set things up on AWS the answer to how might vary from this.

For clustered setups things get more involved to get the right settings for Hazelcast AWS discovery and it is best to use an external ElasticSearch server like an AWS ElasticSearch instance and configure Moqui using environment variables to use the Java REST Client mode instead of the Embedded Node mode. Settings for the moqui-hazelcast and moqui-elasticsearch components can be seen in the MoquiConf.xml file in each component.